# How get waiting follower to follow while trespassing?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm trespassing inside of a house. I activated follower command mode by holding activation while aiming at my follower and told them to wait somewhere. I now can't get them to leave the house with me. They will not comply with an order to leave the house, I cannot access dialogue options to tell them to follow me, and I don't think that there's a way to get the follower to follow me again via command mode. Is the console the only way?

Comment: @Vaishali Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cheatless option 1: Hitting them four times causes them to leave your service. For this purpose, you may want to keep a weak weapon handy. My follower does not turn hostile afterwards. After rehiring them, it only takes one hit for them to leave my service. At that point, it seems to be more of a toss-up whether or not that they'll turn hostile.

[Hashbrown's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/152260/46216) and [kotekzot's commentary answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/152259/how-get-waiting-follower-to-follow-while-trespassing#comment205859_152260) on Hashbrown's are also viable.

Cheatless option 2 ([kotekzot](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/152259/how-get-waiting-follower-to-follow-while-trespassing#comment205859_152260)): Wait until they tire of waiting, then reacquire them.

Console option ([Hashbrown](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/152260/46216)): Bring up the console, click on the NPC that you want to target, then use "moveto player".

Mod option: Follower Trespassing Dialogue Fix - http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=89041053

I compiled all of the options known so far to this answer so I can accept it as all-encompassing.

Answer (score 11):

Although it's an old topic and you've probably resolved the issue, I'm posting, just in case someone else runs into the same problem. I had the same issue, so I commanded Lydia to wait just in front of the exit door. Then I talked to her and while she was giving me the "you' re not supposed to be in here" I immediately exited the building. Sometimes when you enter and exit rooms in the middle of an npc's sentence it causes them to follow you through the door. It worked and I was able to tell her to follow me, as normal then. Hope someone finds this useful.

Answer (score 2):

The [wiki page for followers](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Followers) states

> Most followers will not interact in any way with you while you are trespassing (regardless of their morality); your follower will simply say, "You're not supposed to be in here."

So I think yes, the only way to do it is with the console. One way you could do this is via  the console command `prid (RefID)` to target the follower and then use the command `moveto player` once outside to place them at your current location. You should then be able to talk to them.

Comment: Waiting 3 days and rehiring them is also an option.